# Slow browser video playback on Intel compute stick running ubuntu

Tags: gpu-driver

I have installed ubuntu 14 on my intel compute stick 2gb. When i watch youtube, especially in full screen mode, it's very slow and stuck all the time. The player is html5 not flash. Should i update my video cadr driver, or simply ubuntu is too slow for this device?

P.S.

I used this post as a reference:
https://liliputing.com/2015/07/install-ubuntu-14-04-lts-on-the-2gb-intel-compute-stick.html

Comment: You don't provide enough info. Ubuntu 14.04 is a [little bit old](https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life) try to update. [This](https://askubuntu.com/q/965367/349837) seems a duplicate.