# My Ubuntu Freeze on full screen (online & offline) (Videos & Photos)

Tags: video, freeze

When I go on full screen for example when I see a picture on full screen, play a video on full screen (Youtube or offline), my computer hangs/stucks/freeze. But I still able to open my terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and then I always kill all processors through this command `kill -9 -1`.

Does anyone have a permanent solution for this problem? why my ubuntu always freeze on full screen (offline & Online) (Videos & Photos) 
I started to use Ubuntu by leaving windows but this problem disappointed me. please help me, experts

My System Hardware and other info is below

```
Processor: 2x intel (R) Core (TM) 2 Duo CPU E7500 @ 2.93GHz.
RAM: 4GB. 
Resulution: 1280 x 1024. 
Open GL Rendorer: unknown. 
X11 vendor: The X.org foundation. 
Harddisk: 80 GB 
**Display**              
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 82Q35 Express Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
```

Comment: I think you should provide some hardware details (video drivers and  so).

Comment: **Processor:**  2x intel (R) Core (TM) 2 Duo CPU   E7500 @ 2.93GHz. **RAM:**  4GB.  **Resulution:** 1280 x 1024.  **Open GL Rendorer:** unknown.  **X11 vendor:**  The X.org foundation. **Harddisk:** 80 GB            display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 82Q35 Express Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915

Comment: Please provide the output of this command: `sudo lshw -numeric -C display && ubuntu-drivers devices && glxheads`.